# Can't add button on navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have UItable with items. I have navigation bar etc. On one item in table "Category" I pust another UITable like this:

```
CategoryTableViewController *b = [[CategoryTableViewController alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:b animated:YES];
        [b release];
```

Now I want to add "ADD" button in navigation bar and I add UINavigationBarItem in *.xib connect it to outlets and add it like this in viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.addButton;
```

And this does not work (addButton is null), but when I put the same code for adding button in my first UITable it works fine and "ADD" button is added.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: maybe I was to fast with my answer, but what does " in my first UITable" exactly mean? The same viewController? Which method?

Comment: When my app starts it display first UITable with data. When I click category it push second UITable. If I add button to first table it works but in second it doesn't.

Comment: and both tableviewcontroller instances share the same class?

Comment: Is self.addButton allocated/init before you are assigning it to rightBarButtonItem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ViewController that should show the button in the navigation bar type in the viewDidLoad() method:

```
self.addToolbarButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]           
initWithTitle:@"Add", nil)
    style:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
    target:self
    action:@selector (add)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addToolbarButton;
```

That will add a "add" styled button to the left in the navigation bar which calls the selector method:

```
-(void) add {...}
```

in the same class when it is tapped. In this method in the same class you can specify your add logic. If this method should be placed in a different class, set the target to that.

That is the programatical way to solve this. The method "-(void) add" is what your Outlet has been in the .xib approach.

For your .xib approach you should verify that the Outlet property for the navigationBarButton is set to retain.

Comment: This works. I was retain IBOutlet and connect it in sample project but in my app it doesn't. But this programmatic way works. Thanks :)

Comment: I always do navigation bar issues programmatically cause I never get it work correctly with IB :)

Answer (score 1):

self.addButton is NULL, thus make sure its not NULL. Create a button from code.

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneMeasuring:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

is `[super viewDidLoad];` the first call in your viewDidLoad method?

If not try to put it at the very beginning of viewDidLoad.

Comment: Yes, super viewDidLoad is first in the method.